# How to interact with the local machine while using a Citrix app?

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and I have taken over the development of an app that we provide to our helpdesk for support. The app is simple and developed in C#. All it does it launch the command prompt or powershell under an admin account through Citrix. However, I need to write code that gets around the Citrix session. I am unable to locate what I need on the web.

A good example:
The app has a feature that launches Outlook, the problem is, it launches it through Citrix under the admin account which doesn't have an Exchange account tied to it. When Outlook launches, it asks for setup because it's trying to launch under the admin account. What C# class can I use to circumvent this and talk to the local machine of the user using the app?

Comment: Why does "Citrix" (they make a fair few products, you need to specify which one!) need to be involved at all here? If you just need to run a local app, just run a local app and don't make things complicated.

Comment: Citrix needs to be involved because the app is delivered.... Wait... Through Citrix. This means that the app is actually running on a server and not the local client. Apologies, I thought it was implied what Citrix product I was talking about when I said the app was launched through Citrix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `virtual channel`. That will allow you to communicate between server and client. The client part of the channel might then open Outlook when you send it some special command.